# Error running expo run: android react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an error when I run the expo run:android command for it to run my project...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:lint'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at

Comment: Did you install the `expo-cli`? Try closing your terminal window to refresh environment variables.

Comment: sim, instalei mesmo assim não corrigiu

Comment: hey João, as per [site policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) only english is allowed. The error message is indicating that expo is not being able to find your Android SDK instalation. The easiest way to make sure that is installed is probably installing Android Studio. You should be able to `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` afterwards in your terminal and see a path that corresponds to that location. This is usually very particular on your environment so I would suggest going through the expo docs again and if that doesn't work we can try setting up a chat